# Too short history of builds in TFS

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, tfsbuild, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

We have TFS 2015. One of our build has been red long time. I want to check who first broke build but the history of build results is too short. I click "more builds..." but the history becomes larger only few items. It is amazing that you can not see the whole history. I don't know. Am I doing something wrong? Is there no way of checking whole history? Below screenshot.

[image: Screenshot build history]

Answer (score 2):

This is how the UI works at the moment. The expectation is that teams try to fix their build when it breaks, not let it be broken for days on end.

You can query the builds through the [tfx command line](https://github.com/Microsoft/tfs-cli) (if you have it installed)

```
C:\>tfx build list --status failed --top 200 --project yourproject 
       --definition-name yourbuilddefinition
```

Optionally pass it `--json` to get an easy to parse output and filter it through, for example, Powershell.

Once you've found the build you're looking for you can request the details using

```
C:\>tfx build show --project MyProject --build-id 1364
```

Or just open the web page for the build, the Uri is pretty predictable:

```
https://{account}.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection
       /{project}/_build?_a=summary&buildId={buildid}
```

As you've noticed not all builds are kept, there is a Build Retention policy which will ensure that you're not storing gigabytes of unused data. By default 10 days of builds are retained. (For VSTS: Even if you turn off this pretty restrictive policy your builds will still be deleted by the default policy of VSTS, which is 30 days.)

[image]

If you want to retain your builds indefinitely, then you need to mark the builds.

[image]

Comment: I did that but I got only inforation such as:
[id              : 1364
definition name : Modules.Siren_develop
requested by    : [DefaultCollection]\Project Collection Service Accounts
status          : Completed
queue time      : 2016-04-12T12:21:04.045Z]

There is no informatin about aouthor of push which broke the build.

Comment: O.K. I found the settings "Rationals" in Build Edit view. There I can set  1) Days to keep: 365 2) Delete build record: false 3) Delete source label: false 4) Delete test results: false 4) Branch filters: All. Default is 7 for days to keep. I changed this and now I will have all history but the deleted items I can't resurrection.

Comment: Correct Retention will delete build records after a certain time has expired. You can mark builds as "Retain Indefinitely" to make sure they are retained regardless of policy settings. Once deleted, they're gone though. There is no recycle bin or undo functionality.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will do that.